# Using make file with project with several directories

Tags: c++, makefile, build, g++

This is the make file I am using to compile a simple project.

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
LIBS = -lm
INC = ./inc/
SRC = ./src/

all: volume

%.o: $(INC)%.h $(SRC)%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^

volume: $(SRC)main.o $(SRC)cuboid.o $(SRC)cube.o $(SRC)sphere.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(SRC)*.o $(INC)*.gch volume
```

My project structure:

```
    /
      src/
        .cpp files
      inc/
        .h files
      makefile
```

This compiles fine. I get the output file. But this is a mess, if I have several directories in my project or if I am using MVC in my project using several directories and sub directories. This will easily spiral out of control. What's the proper approach or paradigm to follow here?

Comment: Use `CMake` for larger projects containing multiple directories. Because maintaining `Makefile` manually is very tricky and time-consuming.

Comment: An example implementation would be awesome

Comment: My recommendation for large projects is to have a main top-level project, and the main components of your program are like sub-projects with their own configuration and build files. For example I usually turn each component into a static library which is then linked to the main program. Each component can in turn be divided into even smaller sub-components with their own build configuration. A kind of divide-and-conquer method, where each module is kept (relatively) simple. Decent systems (like CMake or Meson) can automate much of this.